# Where can I get a simple explanation of policy injection?

Tags: enterprise-library, application-blocks, policy-injection

I'd like a dead simple explanation of policy injection for less-informed co-workers.  Where is a good resource for this?  I learned about policy injection from the entlib help files, which I'm sure aren't the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The MSDN documentation for Policy Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309370.aspx) has a pretty clear explanation:

> Applications include a mix of business
>   logic and crosscutting concerns, and
>   the two are typically
>   intermingled—which can make the code
>   harder to read and maintain. Each task
>   or feature of an application is
>   referred to as a "concern." Concerns
>   that implement the features of an
>   object within the application, such as
>   the business logic, are core concerns.
>   Crosscutting concerns are the
>   necessary tasks, features, or
>   processes that are common across
>   different objects—for example,
>   logging, authorization, validation,
>   and instrumentation. The purpose of
>   the Policy Injection Application Block
>   is to separate the core concerns and
>   crosscutting concerns.

Simply put, the PI block lets developers define a set of policies that specify the behavior of objects in the system. So your core business logic, such as the code that calculates profit per unit in a fiscal year (one concern), is separated from the logging of that execution of logic (another, but more often used, concern).

The same documentation says that the PI block is *not* AOP because:

- It uses interception to enable only pre-processing handlers and post-processing handlers.
- It does not insert code into methods.
- It does not provide interception for class constructors.

So trying to look at PI from an AOP perspective can muddy the waters a bit.

Answer (score 1):

What the EntLib calls Policy Injection, is really Aspect Oriented Programming. I wrote a post [introducing the concepts of AOP on my blog](http://iridescence.no/post/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-A-Primer.aspx) a while back, maybe it'll be helpful.